# UITextField – opacity of left placeholder

Tags: ios7, uitextfield, opacity

I have a UITextField with opacity 0.2 (the background is red), and I tried to add a *white* icon as textField.leftView like so:

```
    self.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lock.png"]];
    self.leftView.layer.opacity = 1.0;
    self.layer.opacity = 0.2;
    self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

The problem is that the leftView seems to get the same opacity as the whole text field, and as they both are white, the result is that I see nothing. Do you see any other way/what I do wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the solution. Seems I didn't think it fully through.

The problem was the opacity being "inherited" by all colors of the view, while I only wanted the background to be opaque. So, I just made the background opaque :) Like so:

```
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.2];
```